# Operation timeout (in /var/log/secure)

Tags: ssh

Sometimes when connecting via ssh to my RHEL server, I get the following message back from the client:

> Operation Timeout

Seems like a network problem, but when I look at /var/log/secure on the server I'm connecting to, it actually shows the same message:

> Sep  5 10:47:53 servername sshd[3540]: Received disconnect from ::myip 11: Operation timeout

Some days cause more of these messages than others. Is this the fault of the client, the openssh server or something else, and how can I diagnose what the issue is?

Comment: you have to use the verbose `-v` option of ssh, which can be used upto `-vvv` for more verbose.

Comment: @beginer Unfortunately the client is actually the Rencii sshnet client, which makes it that much more difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Does the problem occur with other clients?  You could also set "LogLevel DEBUG" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to get more information from sshd.  Also, are both the client and server on the same LAN or subnet?